# Postgres JDBC Spring read replica support

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring application which reads/write from/to a Postgresql DB. How do configure the driver such that it auto routes read only transactions to read replicas and incase of replica being down uses master.

I got confused from the documentation https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html about connection-failover.

Is it possible to have R/W connection pool which can autoredirect readonly transactions to replicas ?

Comment: The JDBC driver can not do that as far as I know. But you could use a proxy like [pgPool-II](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II) to do that

Comment: I was expecting somethign similar to MySQL J/Connector. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html It automatically sends read only transactions to read replicas. I don;t want to install a middleware. Is there a better way to seemlessly integrate within Spring application ?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: The way to do it for Postgres is to have 2 separate connection pools. One for Master (jdbc:postgresql://@{rds.host}:@{rds.port}/@{rds.database}?targetServerType=master) and one for Read Replicas and master as a fallback (jdbc:postgresql://@{rds.rr.host}:@{rds.rr.port},@{rds.host}:@{rds.port}/@{rds.database}?targetServerType=preferSlave). Here targetServerType is important. Now with the above configuration you would need a Routing datasource org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager